# how to find the IPs of all the devices connected to a particular server via telnet?

Tags: telnet

There are several computers connecting to one machine via telnet.. I want to find out which are all the systems/IPs which are connected to the machine via telnet... is it possible to find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `netstat` program will tell you what connections are active.  You just need to grep the output for those established and connected to the telnet daemon.

```
sudo netstat --inet -p | grep "/telnetd" | grep ESTABLISHED
```

(or something very close to that -- I don't have a running telnetd service on my machine to verify the command -- you may have to look at the output of netstat directly and adjust the grep strings)